# v-model nested value from schema is always undefined

Tags: vue.js, v-model

I am doing a component in vue.js 2.6

```
<v-sheet class="pa-5">
    <v-form>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="10" md="3" lg="3" xl="3">
          <v-card class="pa-2">
            <h4 class="pb-1 pl-2">Hourly</h4>
            <v-divider />
            <v-row justify="center" class="mt-8 mb-6">
              <v-col cols="10">
                <v-text-field type="text" label="Click" outlined dense v-model="prop1.prop2.hourly.click.value"/>
              </v-col>              
            </v-row>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>   
      </v-row>
    </v-form>
  </v-sheet>
```

and I am obtaining `prop1` value from schema in backend

```
<script lang="ts">
import {  Prop1} from "@pro1-schema";
import {PropType} from "vue";
export default {
  name: "component1-name",
  props: {
    prop1: { type: Object as PropType<Prop1 | null>, default:()=> ({}) },

  },
  data() {

  },
};
</script>
```

intellisense is accurate, always suggesting me correctly the prop that is comming next, wanted to set the variable here

```
<v-text-field type="text" label="Click" outlined dense v-model="prop1.prop2.hourly.click.value"/>
```

in this line but `prop1.prop2` is always undefined.

```
Prop1
export interface Prop1 {
    
    prop2?: PropQuotas;
}
```

```
PropQuotas
export interface PropQuotas {
   
    hourly?: PropQuota;
    
}
```

```
PropQuota
export interface PropQuota {    
    click?: PropQuotaValue;    
}
```

```
PropQuotaValue
export interface PropQuotaValue{    
    value?: number;    
}
```

How to work around this and get rid of this error?

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.prop1.prop2 is undefined"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
prop1: { type: Object as PropType<Prop1 | null>, default:()=> ({}) },
```

Here you're setting the default value of prop1 as an empty object.  It makes sense then that `prop1.prop2` is undefined, because **by default** prop2 doesn't exist on prop1.  Even if some very short time after component creation do you pass down an actual value to prop1 from a parent component, you still need to make sure that your template code can handle `prop1` as it is *before* it has any value.  I have two possible suggestions:

1. Provide default properties when defining prop1, something similar to:

```js
prop1: { type: Object as PropType<Prop1 | null>, 
default:()=> ({
  prop2: {
    hourly: {
      click: {
        value: null
      }
    }
  }}) 
},
```

2. Use v-if to not render the text field until the prop has a value.:

```html
<v-text-field v-if="validProp" type="text" label="Click" outlined dense v-model="prop1.prop2.hourly.click.value"/>
```

```js
computed: {
  validProp() {
    return this.prop1?.prop2?.hourly?.click?.value !== undefined;
  },
},
```

You could optionally abstract this into a generic `isLoading` boolean prop set by the parent based on the current fetch/loading status of prop1

Comment: I can says optional chaining breaks the app, but must be because the not good default config. Trying and testing, and letting you know

Comment: let us say I have several other field after prop2, which wuold be the way of correctly declaring default?

Comment: prop2.hourly  prop2.daily  prop2.monthly...things like that

Comment: sorry, I failed to realize the object was attached to a v-model where the optional chaining won't work.  I've updated my answer to show an alternative using `v-if` that will prevent the text field from rendering until the prop has a valid value.

Comment: but if you want to use default values instead, for prop2.hourly, prop2.monthly, etc. you simply declare each property in the `default:()=>({})` function as an empty object or whatever fallback value you believe those properties should have

Comment: what is the way you like the most, as a 'pro' way...scalable, maintainable, explicit, etc?